# How can I debug a Swift's function call stack?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I have a problem that a screen gets pushed twice. The problem is I don't know which pushViewController that is doing that, and I have so many of them. So I want to add a breakpoint to `navigationController.pushViewController()` function so I can see what is the previous call stack that call that function. I don't need to see the inside of pushViewController. I just need that the breakpoint stop whenever the function pushViewController at navigationController gets called. But I can't put breakpoint on the `open func pushViewController()` at navigationController code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend `UINavigationController` and override `pushViewController` function.

```
class MyNavigationViewController : UINavigationController {
    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

And then you if you are using storyboard, change the class of your navigation controller to `MyNavigationViewController` and also in the code if you creating navigation controller from code.

Comment: I would like to avoid extending UINavigationController for this purpose, but I guess this is inevitable. Thanks.